# Is it possible to have a Site without Site Definition

Tags: 2007, site, site-definition

I am working on a portal and have a site/web and I am trying to find out what site definition its using, I tried this code to find out, it does give me a site template ID and Master page URL, but it Site definition is blank, I was wondering if its possible that there is a site without any site definition.

I am using this code

```
   using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(PageUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = mySite.OpenWeb())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Site definition: {0}", web.WebTemplate); // BLOG
                Console.WriteLine("Web template ID: {0}", web.WebTemplateId); // 9
                Console.WriteLine("Master Page : {0}", web.MasterUrl); // 9
            }
        }
```

it did worked for me many times before tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. All webs have site definition. The name of definition you can get by this code:

```
string id = string.Format("{0}#{1}", web.WebTemplate, web.Configuration)
```

To see what definition is used you can compare result string with values [in this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa978512).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i Use "web.Configuration" it gives me "0"

Comment: it is normal behavior. What kind of WebTemplate do you have?

Comment: WebTemplate id is  "10016" and am not sure how can i find "kind" of WebTemplate is being used :(

Comment: I looked at the post, I Know about configuration, but each site definition have some kind of name, it never should come up as null, unless its not being used

Comment: its STS  Team Site, if thats what you were asking for :)

Comment: so you use STS#0 - it is team site as you say. You can find the difinision (onet.xml) of this site in 'c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\sts\' folder

Comment: yes but we dont have any site definition named as "STS"

Comment: it is out of the box definition.